# Galaxy Y - White Screen Problem

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-y

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y. Yesterday my phone screen went white. I tried restarting, and the same problem occurred. I can receive phone calls and SMS but display fully disappeared - only white screen shows up. Can any one (if one has already faced this problem) tell me how to fix it?

I went to a service center but, he charges too much to fix this problem. So I decided to try manually to fix this problem but still didn't find any solution, not from internet either. I already tried rebooting, hard-reset (removing the battery for a while), and even factory-reset; but none of those solved the issue.

Comment: OK, I've [edited](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48605/edit) that into your question. Unfortunately I have no further ideas; if not even a factory-reset solves it, it very likely is a hardware issue -- so the service center might be your last hope. If that's too expensive, you might consider buying a new device instead :(

Answer (score 1):

The possible reasons for white display are:

1. LCD is completely dead : In this case LCD or display replacement has to be done.
2. LCD connector is effected by carbon or dirt particle: If the LCD connector is surrounded by the carbon then it has to be removed.

There are simple steps which can overcome this problem and can help you in getting your Tab ready for the use.

1-     Switch off the tab and open the back cover

2-     Now  unlock the battery and remove it , it’s not a necessary step. Though it is for the convenience

3-     Get to LCD connector as it is locked, firstly unlock it

4-     After unlocking of LCD  connector , with the help of metal tool rub it to remove the carbon and other dirt particles

5-     Then  fix the connector at earlier position and lock it

6-      Place the battery at its position and connect their terminals

7-     Switch on the tab, now it ready to be used

[Source](http://mytabletguru.com/android-tablet-white-screen-issue-quick-solution/)

Check out this [video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bt2kMKLNxVA) for detail instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Galaxy Y, but mine was in warranty time. I took to an authorized support and they have changed the main board of the smartphone.